# Trying to Execute .bat in Powershell script

Tags: powershell

Trying to execute the below script where i given the comment the "code not working" I want to write the log in to logfile.
 The code which is working is not writting the log into logfile

```
#run email bat file
Write-Host "Running email bat file...... \n"
  #below comand working 
Start-process run.bat -workingdirectory "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus"

 #below code not working 
 Start-Process "cmd" -ArgumentList '/c','D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat', 'connector.log' -WorkingDirectory "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\logs"

 ### tried below code as well but no luck 
   &'D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat' >$emailconnecter_log
    Write-Host $rc

    if (-not $?) 
    { 
    Write-Host $rc
        $status = "running Daily email bat file failed on $hostname";
        Del_Daily
        Del_Dat
    #   Send_Mail
        exit
    }
    else
    {
    Write-Host $rc
    Write-Host "Email send sucess fully....."
    }
```

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: `$prog="cmd.exe";$params=@('/C','D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat','connector.log');start-process $prog $params -WorkingDirectory "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\logs"`

Comment: You have incoherent working dirs in your commands. One has `\Logs` at its tail, the other doesn't.

Comment: I tied this code but no luck. It ran without error, but no email trigged. Do I need to set up something for to call .bat file from Pwershell script.

Comment: you need to double quote your path as it contains a space `$params=@('/C','"D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat"','connector.log')`

Comment: This is how I changed the code `$prog="cmd.exe" $params=@('/C','"D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat"','connector.log') start-process $prog $params -WorkingDirectory "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\logs"` Could you find any issue. Still it is not working

Comment: I got the issue, the code should be having the same path `-WorkingDirectory "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\ ` How can i keep two different path one for .bat and one for log file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a .bat I would use Powershell to send it,

```
send-mailmessage -to "Remote <Someome@place.gov>" -from "Sender <Sender@Place.gov>" -subject "Print Spooler has Stopped" -SmtpServer place.gov
```

Since you are already using powershell for the rest of it.