# Call .bat file from Power Shell

Tags: powershell

Below is my code theris space in directory when i tried to call directly from the script it throws error

```
$emailconnecter_log = "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\logs\connector.log"
& '"D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat"'> $emailconnecter_log
```

as The term '"D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat"' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the s
pelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
Could you help me on this

Comment: Could it just be that you forgot the "over" after -Disc? The path for your log file is different than your command.

Comment: With `&` you don't need double quotes. Drop them.

Comment: This is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246400/trying-to-execute-bat-in-powershell-script

Answer (score 0):

Use either single or double quotes, not both.

These nested double quotes:

```
& '"D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat"'> $emailconnecter_log
   ^                                      ^
```

become part of the file name if you enclose the entire path string in an additional set of single quotes. So you're trying to run a file

```
"D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat"
```

instead of the file

```
D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat
```

which of course fails, because there is no drive `"D:`.

Comment: I tried with `"D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat"  > $emailconnecter_log  run.bat ` and got an errore message as shown below why it is so?   : log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
At D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\Output\Test.ps1:2 char:2
+ & <<<<  "D:\EmailConnector-Disc Optimus\run.bat" > $emailconnecter_log
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (log4j:ERROR set...e) call failed.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: @shagi I already told you 2 questions ago that the error message comes from the code **inside your batch file** and you should post a new question **with your batch code *and* the error message**. Please stop wasting everybody's time and start following instructions.